# Show form field based on text input where text input uses autocomplete

Tags: javascript

I apologize for my ignorance. I am trying to use the following code:

```js
// Use autocomplete for input with id="tagz"
  $( function() {
    var availableTagz = [
      "Accounting Office",
      "Attorney/ Lawyer Office"
    ];
    $( "#tagz" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTagz
    });
// display div if user types Attorney/ Lawyer Office  
      checkInd();
      $('#tagz').change(checkInd);

      function checkInd() {
        var riskind = $("input[id='tagz']").val();
       
          if ( riskind == "Attorney/ Lawyer Office" ) {
            document.getElementById('highrisk').style.display = 'block';
          }
        else {
          document.getElementById('highrisk').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
        
        
      }
    });
```

```css
#highrisk {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="tagz" name="properties[industry]" value="" type="text" required>
<div id="highrisk">
<!--Other conditional inputs go here-->
</div>
```

If the user fills in the input as "Attorney/ Lawyer Office", I want the div to display. The autocomplete is working, but I can't get the div to show. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

EDIT ---
Sorry, I don't know the best way to post this to the forum. I found that the following code works if you type the whole value into the input field, but does not work if you select the value from the autocomplete "drop-down." Any help to figure out how to make it work with the autocomplete would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
function checkInd() {
  var riskind = document.getElementById("tagz").value;
    if (riskind == "Attorney/ Lawyer Office" ) {
        document.getElementById('highrisk').style.display = 'block';
    }
   else {
     document.getElementById('highrisk').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('risk2').style.display = 'none';
   }

}    
</script>
<input id="tagz" name="properties[Industry]" value="" type="text" required onchange="checkInd()" onkeyup="checkInd()">
```

Comment: you have a closing bracket that doesn't close anything, just after the `else` clause --> `);` -- remove that line...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question, but the code still doesn't work for changing the display property upon inputting "Attorney/ Lawyer Office"